# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable,any other solutions except implements java.io.Serializable

Tags: java, apache-spark

I got this error when I used UDF functions in my spark(write by java) application.

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:403)
        ...
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: jp.co.nec.necdas.commons.customize.service.dataset.ALMTriggerProcessLogic
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: jp.co.nec.necdas.commons.customize.service.dataset.ALMTriggerProcessLogic, value: jp.co.nec.necdas.commons.customize.service.dataset.ALMTriggerProcessLogic@f237ae7)

And this is my code:

```
//"alarmMeasure" is a dataset from postgres 
//"macroInfo" is also a dataset,but from csv
alarmMeasure.sparkSession().sqlContext().udf().register("genrateKeyId", new UDF2<String,String,String>() {

                @Override
                public String call(String almDetectionCode,String time) throws Exception {
                    StringBuilder keyId = new StringBuilder();
                    time = DateTimeUtils.transform(time,"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss","yyyyMMddhhmm");
                    keyId.append("KNLG");
                    keyId.append("_");
                    keyId.append(almDetectionCode);
                    keyId.append("_");
                    keyId.append(time);
                    return keyId.toString();
                }
            }, DataTypes.StringType);
Dataset tmp = alarmMeasure.join(macroInfo,alarmMeasure.col("deviceName")
                    .equalTo(macroInfo.col("deviceName")),"inner")
                    .drop(macroInfo.col("deviceName"));
tmp.withColumn("KeyId",functions.callUDF("genrateKeyId",tmp.col("alarmDectionCode"),tmp.col("alarmDectionCode").show();
```

Some blogs told me that I should implements java.io.Serializable,so I tried but got same error like this:

Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: jp.co.nec.necdas.commons.spark.SparkContextManager
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: jp.co.nec.necdas.commons.spark.SparkContextManager, value: jp.co.nec.necdas.commons.spark.SparkContextManager@153cfd86)

"SparkContextManager" is an API used in my class,does it means that I have to ensure all the class used in my class implements java.io.Serializable?

Comment: what is your spark and java version?  you can achieve same result using spark sql without udfs, just fyi

Comment: `"SparkContextManager" is an API used in my class,does it means that I
have to ensure all the class used in my class implements
 java.io.Serializable?`

Unfortunately yes, as far as I know, Spark performs nested serializability check and even if one class from an external API does not implement `Serializable` you will get errors. As @chlebek notes above, it is indeed much easier to utilize Spark SQL without UDFs to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for you help @chlebek,@etherealyn,Unfortunately I can not just use spark sql because the real logic is more complicate.But I did find a solution, by using '@Expose(serialize = false)' and declaring 'sparkContextManager' as a static class.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Objects not serializable should be defined as static, as static fields are not part of the object and they are not serialised.
2. Instantiate the non-serializable object upon first usage, so it is not part of the serializable object sent to the Worker(s).

Actually the second option is that one I am using in my current project, where our UDF has to use an external jar that we cannot modify.